# allow only the h1 and the parent element to trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML

```
<div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordion_header">
        <h1>Header Title</h1>
        <button>sample button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion_content">
        <p>accordion content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this script

```
$(".accordion .accordion_header").click(function(e){
    if (e.target !== this)return;
    var $sub = $(this).next('.accordion_content').stop(true, true);
    if ($sub.is(':visible')) {
        $sub.slideUp();
    } else {
        $sub.slideDown();
    }         
});
```

as you can see from the above reference, the function (slideDown, slideUp thing) will only trigger when the parent (.accordion_header) is click and will not trigger into its children (when its click), however, how can I make it to trigger the function (slideUp, slideDown stuff of the .accordion_content) only allowed to the parent ".accordion_header" and its children h1?

any help, suggestion, recommendation, ideas, clues will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand it, you can use following check:

```
if (e.target !== this && $(e.target).is(':not(h1)')) return;
```

### -DEMO-

Comment: this works if only I have a text inside my h1 but if I have like this "<span class="tp ketchup" title="Click to view"><i class="pe-7s-angle-down"></i></span><span>CLIENTS DATA TABLE</span>" its not working

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you want, because the description is ambiguous.

```
$(".accordion").on('click','h1,.accordion_header',function(e){
    if (e.target !== this)return;
    if (this.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'h1'){
        $sub = $(this).parent().next('.accordion_content');
    }
    else{
        $sub = $(this).next('.accordion_content');
    }
    if ($sub.is(':visible')) {
        $sub.slideUp();
    } else {
        // slide up the opened accordion_content
        //$('.accordion_content:visible').slideUp(); 
        $sub.slideDown();
    }         
});
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vasilenicusor/gohpbgv9/4/)